# Modal windows/popups don't work with isotope filtering

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="portfolio-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="btn btn-primary active" ; data-filter="*" ;>*</li>
                        <li class="btn btn-primary" ; data-filter=".A" ;>A</li>
                        <li class="btn btn-primary" ; data-filter=".B" ;>B</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item row">
                    <div class="A col-lg-3" ; data-bs-toggle="modal" ; data-bs-target="#A1" ;>
                        <p>Image #1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" ; id="A1" ; tabindex="-1" ; aria-labelledby="A1-LBL" ; aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Text (Image #1) ...</p>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ; id="A1-LBL" ; data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="B col-lg-3" ; data-bs-toggle="modal" ; data-bs-target="#B1" ;>
                        <p>Image #2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" ; id="B1" ; tabindex="-1" ; aria-labelledby="B1-LBL" ; aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Text (Image #2) ...</p>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ; id="B1-LBL" ; data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script>
            $('.portfolio-menu ul li').click(function() {
                $('.portfolio-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $('.portfolio-item').isotope({
                    filter: selector
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My experience is that modal windows/popups works like a charm when applied on buttons and other type of clickable elements with one exception - isotope filtering (bootstrap)

They seem to get a life of their own regarding positioning and height.

The code below gives you an example of how they behave.

If you click on “Image #1”  the modal window will be positioned correctly with expected height and width.
But when you “filter your images” (Click on “A” or “B”) and then try to open the modal window in the resultset by clicking on “Image #1” or “Image #2” (depending on your choice of filtering) you will see that the modal window is decreased in height and the position is “wrong”.
If you then click “*” (resetting the filtering) then the positioning and height are still wrong.

What have I missed ? Or is this the way modal windows should behave?

Any help would be highly appreciated.